# Neural net with non standard input

Tags: keras

I want to make a neural net which takes image+image+value as an input and performs convolution+pooling on images and then a linear transform on results. Can I do that in keras?

Comment: Is the order and the number of image fixed?

Comment: @Craig.Li yes, exactly two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is architecturally similar to Craig Li's answer but is in the image, image, value format and does not use VGG16 and just a vanilla CNN. These are 3 separate networks whose outputs are concatenated after being processed individually and the resulting concatenated vector is passed through the final layers, including information from all inputs.

```
input_1 = Input(data_1.shape[1:], name = 'input_1')
conv_branch_1 = Conv2D(filters, (kernel_size, kernel_size),
                 activation = LeakyReLU())(conv_branch_1)
conv_branch_1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))(conv_branch_1)
conv_branch_1 = Flatten()(conv_branch_1)

input_2 = Input(data_2.shape[1:], name = 'input_2')
conv_branch_2 = Conv2D(filters, (kernel_size, kernel_size),
                 activation = LeakyReLU())(conv_branch_2)
conv_branch_2 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2))(conv_branch_2)
conv_branch_2 = Flatten()(conv_branch_2)

value_input = Input(value_data.shape[1:], name = 'value_input')
fc_branch = Dense(80, activation=LeakyReLU())(value_input)

merged_branches = concatenate([conv_branch_1, conv_branch_2, fc_branch])
merged_branches = Dense(60, activation=LeakyReLU())(merged_branches)
merged_branches = Dropout(0.25)(merged_branches)
merged_branches = Dense(30, activation=LeakyReLU())(merged_branches)

merged_branches = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(merged_branches)

model = Model(inputs=[input_1, input_2, value_input], outputs=[merged_branches])

#if binary classification do this otherwise whatever loss you need

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy')
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your image is RGB type, the shape of the image is (width,height,3), you can combine two images with `numpy` like:

```
    import numpy as np
    from PIL import Image

    img1 = Image.open('image1.jpg')
    img2 = Image.open('imgae2.jpg')

    img1 = img1.resize((width,height))
    img2 = img2.resize((width,height))

    img1_arr = np.asarray(img1,dtype='int32')
    img2_arr = np.asarray(img2,dtype='int32')

    #shape of img_arr is (width,height,6)
    img_arr = np.concatenate((img1_arr,img2_arr),axis=2)
```

Combine two images in this way, we only increase the channels, so we can still do convolution on the first two axis.

**UPDATE:**
I guess you mean Multi-Task Model, you want to merge two images after convolution,Keras has `concatenate()` can do that.

```
    input_tensor = Input(shape=(channels, img_width, img_height))
    # Task1 on image1
    conv_model1 = VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights=None, include_top=False, classes=classes,
                  input_shape=(channels, img_width, img_height))
    conv_output1 = conv_model1.output
    flatten1 = Flatten()(conv_output1)
    # Task2 on image2
    conv_model2 = VGG16(input_tensor=input_tensor, weights=None, include_top=False, classes=classes,
                  input_shape=(channels, img_width, img_height))
    conv_output2 = conv_model2.output
    flatten2 = Flatten()(conv_output2)
    # Merge the output
    merged = concatenate([conv_output1, conv_output2], axis=1)
    merged = Dense(classes,activation='softmax')(merged)

    # add some Dense layers and Dropout,
    final_model = Model(inputs=[input_tensor,input_tensor],outputs=merged)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yet I want to have different weights on my convolutions on either image. So I want it to be more like kind of different layers which are in the end connected.

Comment: Once again, thank you for answering. convolutionBoy was closer to what I wanted to have (hence the name).